# how to query two tables at once

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a little trouble. I would like to retrieve information that is listed in $tbl_name_2 without messing up the login. Not sure exactly how to do this. I am self taught and don't know to much about php and mysql. Here is some of my code

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="";
$username="";
$password="";
$db_name="player";
$tbl_name="info";
$tbl_name_2="primary";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT $tbl_name.* FROM $tbl_name WHERE userid='$userid' and passid='$passid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)):

//From $tbl_name
$id = $rows['id'];
$cash = $rows['cash'];
$level = $rows['level'];

//From $tbl_name_2 Primary
$name = $row['name'];
$buy = $row['buy'];
?>

<p>
     <?php echo $_SESSION["userid"]; ?>&#91;<?php echo "$id"; ?>&#93;
</p>
<p>
    <?php if ($cash < 0): ?>   
    <span> -&#36;<?php echo ($cash * -1); ?></span>
    <?php else: ?>    
    <span> &#36;<?php echo $cash; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
<p>
     <?php echo $name ; ?>
</p>

<?php
endwhile;
mysql_close();
?>
```

Here is a little info on the tables:

```
info table 
id     userid     cash     level     primaryid
----------------------------------------------
1      user1     100        1          2
2      user2     150        2          2
3      user2     300        4          1

primary table 
primaryid     name     buy     sale
------------------------------------
1             AR15     10        5
2             M16      50        10
```

What i am trying to do is:

```
userid     level     cash     name    bought for
------------------------------------------------
user1       1        100     M16        50
```

and be able to put whichever item each player has anywhere on my page.

Comment: join or subquery comes to mind but i don't completely understand the question.

Comment: Please add both tables with some sample data to your question with the desired result.

Comment: how are you tying the two tables together? There doesn't appear to be a common column between them.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using JOINS so you can retrieve values from more than one table, check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit hard to understand, but I think what you're trying to do is:

Get a users information (id, cash and level) from first table (info), but you would also like the name from the second table (primary).

To achive this, you would have to use SQL JOINs. To be able to join the tables, you must have one identifier in the second table, that would create a link to a specific row in the first table.

Example of this:

```
Table1
id      cash     level
----------------------
1       5        2
2       10       4


Table2
id      infoid   name
----------------------
1       2        Robin
2       1        Adam
```

With this kind of table layout you could easily write a SQL-query like this one:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.cash, Table1.level, Table2.name FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.infoid
```

That query would return data from both table1 and table2, by joining them together where the infoid from table2 is the same as the id from table1.

The return would be something like:

```
id     cash    level    name
1      5       2        Adam
2      10      4        Robin
```

There are some good examples of this at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)